# Do I cut top of new mimosa tree?

Tags: pruning

We planted a mimosa tree in February- March 2023. It was fairly small. started off really good. Then leaves started to turn yellow then brownish. It seemed to not be growing much.
Then recently the leaves came back. The bottom part of truck started growing branches. So now there is a 3-4 inch gap. Should we cut the top?

Comment: Lacking pictures or details about the plant, sounds like a "top graft died, rootstock sprouted" tale. Which assumes it was a grafted tree, but then, I'm left to assume without further details.